# express and cookie-session for production?

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies

I am at the early stage of an application and i am trying to understand whats the best way to make secure sessions, i usually go for cookie-session and express, is this ok or is it required a better approach?

An example of the code i use (dont count the users part which is an array in production that will be a model coming from a mysql db for example)

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('cookie-session');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(session({
    name: 'session',
    keys: ['key1', 'key2'],
    secret: 'secret',
    cookie: {
      secure: true,
      httpOnly: false,
      path: 'foo/bar',
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000 * 24 * 365)
    }
  }));

users = [
    {
        "id":1,
        "email":"mail@gmail.com",
        "username":"username",
        "userpass":"userpass123"
    }
];

app.get("/home",function(req,res){
    res.send(req.session.user);
})

app.post("/login",(req,res)=>{
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if(req.body.email == users[i].email){
            if(req.body.userpass == users[i].userpass){
                req.session.user = users[i];
                return res.redirect("/home");
            }
        }
    }
    return res.redirect("/");
});

app.get("/logout",(req,res)=>{
    req.session.destroy();
    return res.send("/");
});

function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next()
    }

    res.redirect('/login')
}

function checkNotAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.redirect('/')
    }
    next()
}

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("Server started...");
})
```

also what's the best way of storing sessions?

Comment: Using `cookie-session` should do the job for you. It's secure and easy to use. I'd recommend storing sessions in a file or a database table.

Comment: So what node module do you suggest to save sessions in the filesystem?

Comment: I'd recommend you to use `session-file-store` module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-file-store).